# Changing color using hue is creating unwanted border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I have an image with green and blue stones:

[image]

I want to change all the green ones to be blue as well.

Currently I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9fwiNyDHLI

It says to:

1) Select > Color Range
2) Use the dropper on the green stone to select all the greens
3) Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Hue/Saturation

However, when I do this, it adds an unwanted dark border around the green stones and I can still see some green:

[image]

Is there a way to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Layer above the image and pick a light blue.. fill that layer with the blue. Then set the layer Blending Mode to **Hue**.

[image]

Everything turns blue.

Add a **mask** to the color layer and mask away the hand....

[image]

Command/Ctrl-Click the mask thumbnail to load it as a selection. Create a new layer. Inverse the selection (Select > Inverse) and then fill the selection with the same blue. Set this layer's blend mode *also* to **Hue**.

[image]

Control/Right-click this blue hand layer in the Layers Panel (click near the name) and choose **Blending Options** from the pop up menu.

[image]

Note the 2 sliders at the bottom of the blending options window.

Moving the bottom left slider indicator the the right will cause the blue to blend with the original image (the layers below it). To split that slider arrow hold down the Option/Alt key when you click-drag and it will split apart. By splitting the slider you can control the drop in/out of the blend, making is softer. Play with the slider until you can eliminate most of the green glow on the hand, but keep as much of the red skin tones as possible.

[image]

With more care you can mask and blend the color on the hand better to smooth the transition to the green glows. There's really no quick and easy method to get rid of those glows without also altering the red of the hand, so careful masking would be better. This is merely a quick example of possibilities.

Comment: wow you are a magician... thanks for all the directions!!!

Comment: would you mind uploading a pic of the original pic with all your edits? I noticed yours is chopped off a bit on the top.

Comment: I didn't save anything.. did it and threw it away. My goal was to show you *how to do it* not create an image for you. There should be no reason you need to see the portion of the image I cropped off in the screenshots.

Comment: noooooo :( i'm stuck at the "Command/Ctrl-Click..."